# Does Oracle 10g work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to install Oracle 10g on Windows 7 but in the installation I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point GetProcessImageFileNameW could not be located in the dynamic library PSAPI.DLL.

Does Oracle 10g work on Windows 7?

Comment: Which part/edition of Oracle? Server, client? XE? Please add some more infos!

Answer (score 2):

It seems your installer is using the wrong psapi.dll as the one in `%windir%\system32` should export the `GetProcessImageFileNameW` function.

You can verify that with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Search your system for other versions of psapi.dll and remove them.

Also, if another application is using that dll, you will not be able to remove it. Use [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) to see which process is using it.

Answer (score 2):

The first officially supported release of the Oracle RDBMS on Win7 is 11gR2.

Oracle plans to support the 10.2.0.5 client on Win7.

Information obtained from Metalink.

That said, you *might* be able to get 10g running - there's just no guarantee.