# Installing Oracle Database 11g Express on Windows 64-bit

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to install and set up Oracle Database 11g Express Edition onto a Windows 64bit system at all?

Comment: Similar: [Does Oracle 10g work on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/71368/does-oracle-10g-work-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 Better question: Where can I download 10g now that Oracle no longer provides downloads?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to their [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html):

> - **Does not work in Windows x64**

According to the [requirements page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#BABGGAJA) for "11g Release 2 (11.2) for Microsoft Windows":

> System architecture -- Intel (x86)

To pull it off you'll probably have to run a VM with either 32-bit Windows, or a 64-bit Linux installed as the OS.

Comment: Neither of those are sufficient.  They only provide an RPM package for Linux, which is not usable on Ubuntu Linux without problems.

Comment: Neither of which are sufficient?  You asked if it could be installed on 64-bit Windows, and the answer is (currently) No - you'll need to use 32-bit Windows or a 64-bit Linux.  If Ubuntu can't handle the RPM, then I guess you'll need a different Linux distribution. :)

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure what help you're expecting?

Comment: The problem is I have an application to deploy for a client that DEPENDS on Oracle 11g.  Problem is, I can't test the deployment because of lack of an Oracle DB setup.  Your "suggestion" of using a different linux distribution is in and of itself infeasible, and if this can't be set up on 64bit Windows Servers or 64bit Win7 systems, then what good is Oracle?  (POS software, perhaps?)

Comment: You're not going to get any arguments from me: Oracle sucks, and this is _a_ reason why. :)  Do the application authors have any suggestions?  Can't you split the DB roles away from the App to a different (compatible) server?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I would PREFER that everything run on MySQL or similar.  But alas people are generally idiots.  I dropped them an email, its up to them now.  If they redid all the SQL for, say, MySQL, that would make life easier.  But generally people are somewhat stupider than that, so... no clue how this'll be resolved.

Comment: Too bad Oracle owns MySQL now too. :(

Comment: True, but they haven't botched it up like they have OracleDB yet.

Comment: dosen't windows do side by side? There's no reason you couldn't install and run windows 32 bit binaries on a 64 bit systen

Comment: 32 bit stuff works on 64 bit machines

Comment: @adymitruk So you've gotten the Oracle 11g 32-bit version to successfully install and run on a 64-bit Windows?